# Proper way of finding modules with RTL, Jest and StoryBook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, storybook

I'm using RTL, Jest and StoryBook in my project (React + TypeScript)

Inside my `scr` folder I have a folder which is called `entities`. For example - `src/entities/User`

**Problem**

When I run RTL and StoryBook tests it says that it can't find `entities/User` module

**Decision**

I noticed that StoryBook gives me that error message - `Module not found: Error: Package path ./User is not exported from package D:\Practice\VisualCode\projects\Example-17\project\node_modules\entities`

As you can see `node_modules` folder also has a folder which name is `entities` and it goes to `node_modules/entities` to try to find `User`. But `User` is located in `src/entities/User`

If I rename folder `entities` in `src` all tests go without errors.

I need to save the name of the folder `entities` inside `src` and don't understand why it goes inside `node_modules/entities` folder to find `User`

Here is my configs for Jest and SB. Pay attention to comments inside it which explain what I tried to solve the problem.

**Jest:**

```
{
    "clearMocks": true,
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["\\\\node_modules\\\\"],
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"], // <= ['src', 'node-modules'] ALSO DOESN'T HELP
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "mjs",
        "cjs",
        "jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "json",
        "node"
    ],
    "rootDir": "../../",
    "modulePaths": ["<rootDir>src"],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testMatch": ["<rootDir>src/**/*(*.)@(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"],
    "globals": {
        "__IS_DEV__": true,
        "__API__": ""
    },
    "setupFiles": ["whatwg-fetch"],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>config/jest/setupTests.ts"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "\\.(scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
        "\\.svg": "<rootDir>src/shared/lib/tests/jest/__mocks__/svg.tsx",
        "^entities/User$": "<rootDir>/src/entities/User" // <= I CAN PUT THIS PATH MANUALLY TO PASS THE TESTS, IT CAN'T FIND THIS MODULE WITHOUT IT. BUT IT GOES ONLY FOR RTL TESTS
    }
}
```

**Webpack config for StoryBook:**

```
export default ({
    config
}: {
    config: webpack.Configuration
}): webpack.Configuration => {
    const paths: BuildPaths = {
        entry: '',
        build: '',
        html: '',
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src')
    }

    const definePlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        __IS_DEV__: JSON.stringify(true),
        __API__: JSON.stringify('')
    })

    config.resolve?.modules?.push(paths.src)
    config.resolve?.extensions?.push('.ts', '.tsx')

    if (config.module?.rules !== undefined) {
        // @ts-expect-error RuleSetRule
        config.module.rules = config.module?.rules?.map((rule: RuleSetRule) => {
            if (String(rule.test).includes('svg')) {
                return { ...rule, exclude: /\.svg$/i }
            }
            return rule
        })
    }

    config.module?.rules?.push(buildSVGLoader())
    config.module?.rules?.push(buildCSSLoader(true))
    config.plugins?.push(definePlugin)

    return config
}
```

**Question:**

I don't want to rename my folder `entities` inside `src` to pass all tests. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?